# Why is running faster more tiring, per kilometer?

Tags: running

Clearly, running fast is harder than running slow. If I run a 5k in 30 minutes, I will be panting harder and feel more uncomfortable by the end of it than if I jog it in 45 minutes.

Why is this? How can we quantify the difference? An obvious thing to try is to count calories - what is the energy cost of running a certain distance at a certain speed? However, it seems to be fairly well accepted that calories per kilometer is constant, independently of your speed. See e.g. *Margaria et al. 1963, Energy cost of running*. The claim is also stated very clearly in Carrier et al. 1984, which cites the first paper:

> ...the cost of transport for a running human does not depend on speed. Consequently, a man running a marathon will consume the same amount of energy for transport whether he runs at a slow jog or at a world-class pace.

If not calories, what is an appropriate way to measure "perceived effort" of running a given distance at a given speed?

Comment: Pity this got closed as off topic without suggestions of a better SE site for it because it's a good question IMHO... PhysicalFitness.SE maybe?  (Or Biology?)